# Running Openbox and MATE in parallel with KDE causes freezing on Debian

Tags: debian, kde, desktop-environment, freeze, sddm

I am running Parrot OS (Debian) with KDE as the default desktop environment and SDDM as the display manager. I want to run Openbox and MATE desktop environments parallel to KDE on different virtual terminals. However, when I switch back to KDE after running Openbox or MATE on a different virtual terminal, the KDE desktop freezes and shows the last frame from Openbox or MATE or a black screen.

I started Openbox on TTY3 using the command `startx /usr/bin/openbox -- :1` and MATE on TTY2 using `startx /usr/bin/mate-session -- :2`. Both sessions work fine, but the KDE session on TTY7 freezes when I switch back to it.

If I set Mate as the default desktop environment. And start another Mate or Openbox on a different virtual terminal. And switch between them, the Mate started by SDDM also freezes, the others are working fine.

If I use LightDM instead of SDDM I get the same problem.

How can I fix this issue and switch between the different desktop environments seamlessly without freezing the desktop environment session on TTY7 (started by the desktop manager)?